# Is there a value for MySQL "null" date (0001-01-01)

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

In my DB, there is a non-nullable Date column. When I provide no date, the value reads 0001-01-01.

However, in the client, I need to know when the column is empty, and for that I use a silly condition:

```
if (Record.Year == 1)
{
   ///the column is empty, show "N/A" for date
}
```

Isn't there a more elegant way than this (the DB column cannot be changed)?

Comment: Make it nullable. Don't play games or you're going to end up with *problems*. If it "cannot" be changed you're in for a world of hurt no matter what "magical" date you pick. You might be able to use `0000-00-00` but it's dumb and looks like a data error. This is how you end up with people 2000 years old and invoices with two millennia of back interest tacked on.

Comment: Write a view that maps the dodgy data to `NULL` (like it should be). That way you _store_ it wrong, but _retrieve_ it correctly.

Comment: This is the exact use case for a nullable column. Fix the DB design and turn any non-sense dates into proper `NULL` values.

Comment: I fail to understand if you want to store nulls or not. Then you can decide how to deal with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By chosing to define that column `NOT NULL` you told the database, that there always needs to be a (presumably valid) date there. If this doesn't fit your business logic, then you have only two possibilities:

- Match business logic and DB model (`ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN ...`)
- Live with this bad match: This **will** include crutches like "magic values" and it is very likely to lead to more trouble further down the road.

Comment: lol 
the advise ;p